# Merging PHP array items and incrementing numerical values

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = [
        0 => [
            'product' => 'ABC',
            'buyprice' => 100,
            'sellprice' => 200
        ],
        1 => [
            'product' => 'ZZZ',
            'buyprice' => 100,
            'sellprice' => 200
        ],
        2 => [
            'product' => 'ABC',
            'buyprice' => 100,
            'sellprice' => 200
        ],
    ];
```

And I want to merge elements based on the product value to look like this:

```
    $array2 = [
        0 => [
            'product' => 'ABC',
            'buyprice' => 200,
            'sellprice' => 400
        ],
        1 => [
            'product' => 'ZZZ',
            'buyprice' => 100,
            'sellprice' => 200
        ]
    ];
```

I have thought about looping through the array, then looking for new instances of product in the same array but it seems convoluted and I wondered if there was a simple way of achieving this that I may be overlooking?

Comment: Try this...
`$res = [];
foreach($array as $ar)
{
    if(sizeof($res))
    {
        foreach($res as $key => $re)
        {
            if($ar['product'] == $re['product'])
            {
                $res[$key]['buyprice']  = $re['buyprice']+$ar['buyprice'];
                $res[$key]['sellprice'] = $re['sellprice']+$ar['sellprice'];
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $res[] = $ar;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $res[] = $ar;
    }
}
print_r($res);`

Comment: Try this - `collect($array)->unique()->toArray()`

Comment: $array = collect($array)->groupBy("product")->map(function ($products) {
        return [
            "product" => $products[0]["product"],
            "buyprice" => collect($products)->sum("buyprice"),
            "sellprice" => collect($products)->sum("sellprice"),
        ];
    })
        ->values()
        ->toArray();